# What is the correct way of using angular 2 partially in an application?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Every single example I have come across with angular 2, expects the Angular 2 to be used on every single page and expects the AppComponent to exist on the page. If an AppComponent is missing, there is a following error:

```
Error in :0:0 caused by: The selector "my-app" did not match any elements
```

What is the correct and preferred way of using angular 2 partially within an application, whereas rest of the app is rendered on the server side?

In Angular 1, you could just not include `ng-app` directive, if a specific page did not require angular. What is the angular 2's equivalent of not having `ng-app` directive?

Answer (score 1):

You can actually learn how angular2 bootstraps itself. Look at the transpiled code in the main file to see how it's done and add your own logic to the page to determine whether or not to run it.

Comment: I thought the point of using Angular was to avoid having to do this. Angular1's elegance is that you don't have to conditionally bootstrap if such directive didn't exist.

Comment: Angular2 is designed to load on any page it's included in. I'm just giving a suggestion that goes against the way its designed; the better way is to just not load it in the pages it's not used.

Comment: I see, thanks for your suggestion. I wasn't meaning to be rude or anything, I'm just trying to wrap my head around this.

Comment: Oh no worries... I learned a lot from questioning stuff just as you had :)

Answer (score 1):

If the app that is rendered on the server side can include scripts and tags required for bootstrapping Angular2 application. Other parts of the application would render HTML as usual without Angular 2 tags and directives. The only difference is that the same links require `href` attribute instead of `routerLink`.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @Paul Jerome Bordallo's answer, we can change the bootstrap script to look like this:

```
const elemExists = document.getElementById("load-angular");

if(elemExists) {
    platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
}
```

So on your html, we could have something like:

```
<my-app id="load-angular"></my-app>
```

to get the functionally we want.

Comment: The part that used to control  if `elemExists` could be done on server side.